# window.open doesn't open the link address stored in react useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I load a link address from a firestore document into a react state variable and use window.open({state_variable}) giving the state_variable as argument which should open the link address stored in the variable in a new tab but instead it opens a local link of the form: [image: Link address ss]

I have created a handleUpload function for a button that uploads an image to firestore and then i call the function window.open({state_variable})

Comment: It looks like `state_variable` is an object, what does it output if you `console.log(state_variable)` ?

Comment: Also you don't need the curlys `{}` i think that's why it believes that is an object, try just with: `window.open(state_variable)`

Comment: Hey Toni, it worked when i removed the curlys {} ,thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad I could help, I added it as an answer so you can accept it. ciao!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it must be thinking its an object because you are using the curly `{}` which you shouldn't need, please try like this:

`window.open(state_variable)`

best regards